# How to load just the active relationships in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query and I am loading 3 relations as below:

```
$data = Hotel::with('rooms.discount')
            ->whereHas('rooms.discount')->paginate(10);

return DiscountResource::collection($data);
```

relations like below :

```
public function Rooms()
{
    return $this->Hasmany(Room::class);
}
```

and the discount relation with room

```
public function discount()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Discount::class, 'id', 'room_id');
}
```

So now every hotel has 50 hotels for example and among them only 1 room has the discount I want just to show that 1 room this code now shows all rooms nether they have discount or not if not it shows null for them but I don't want to show the room without discount in my API because it can make it so heavy.

Comment: please add ```rooms``` and ```discount``` relations

Comment: checkout my edited question

Comment: a side note. it should be ```->hasMany```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it looks like tablea are realted in such a way:

Hotel[id], Room[id, hotel_id], Discount[id, room_id]

That means that Rooms->Discount is not belongsTo() -> it is hasMany(), hence should be named as: Room->Discounts() - so one room has several discounts:

```
public function discounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Discount::class, 'id', 'room_id');
}
```

And based on this - there could be placed one more relation in Hotel:

```
public function roomDiscounts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Discount::class, Room::class, 'hotel_id', 'room_id', 'id', 'id');
}
```

So, you want to find all hotels where rooms have discounts:

```
$hotels = Hotel::whereHas('roomDiscounts')->get();
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem can you please a bit exaplain how the hasmany through is doing here ? thanks

Comment: Happy that it helped. HasManyThrough - is relationship which helps to relate two tables via intermediate one like in your case exactly. More info and examples about that you can find here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through